# word analysis and scoring from a file python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, cpu-word, sentiment-analysis

I am doing a word by word analysis of a sentence such as 
"Hey there!! This is a excellent movie???"

I have many sentences like above.
I have a huge dataset file like shown below where I have to do a quick lookup if that word exists. If it does then do analysis and store in a dictionary such as get the score from the file of the word, score of last word of sentence, first word of sentence and so on.

sentence[i] => Hey there!! This is a excellent movie???
sentence[0] = Hey, sentence[1]=there!! sentence[2]=This and so on.

Here is the code:

```
def unigrams_nrc(file):
   for line in file:
       (term,score,numPos,numNeg) = re.split("\t", line.strip())
       if re.match(sentence[i],term.lower()):
          #presence or absence of unigrams of a target term
          wordanalysis["unigram"] = found
       else:
          found = False
       if found:
          wordanalysis["trail_unigram"] = found if re.match(sentence[(len(sentence)-1)],term.lower()) else not(found)
          wordanalysis["lead_unigram"] = found  if re.match(sentence[0],term.lower()) else not(found)
          wordanalysis["nonzero_sscore"] = float(score) if (float(score) != 0) else 0             
          wordanalysis["sscore>0"] = (float(score) > 0)
          wordanalysis["sscore"] = (float(score) != 0)

       if re.match(tweet[len(sentence)-1],term.lower()):
          wordanalysis["sscore !=0 last token"] = (float(score) != 0)
```

Here is the file (more than 4000 words in this file):

```
#fabulous   7.526   2301    2
#excellent  7.247   2612    3
#superb 7.199   1660    2
#perfection 7.099   3004    4
#terrific   6.922   629 1
#magnificent    6.672   490 1
#sensational    6.529   849 2
#heavenly   6.484   2841    7
#ideal  6.461   3172    8
#partytime  6.111   559 2
#excellence 5.875   1325    6
@thisisangel    5.858   217 1
#wonderful  5.727   3428    18
elegant 5.665   537 3
#perfect    5.572   3749    23
#fine   5.423   2389    17
excellence  5.416   279 2
#realestate 5.214   114 1
bicycles    5.205   113 1
```

I wanted to know if there is a better way to do the above? 
Defining better way: Faster, less code and elegant.
I am new to python so I know this is not the best code. I have around 4 files through which I have to go and check the score hence want to implement this function in the best possible way.

Comment: Define "better way"? Faster, less code, elegance? It looks like your solution is well written enough. I assume it works?

Comment: I could suggest storing the file as JSON so you can simply ``json.laods(data)`` the data file.

Comment: @JamesMills better way would be faster, less code and elegant. My solution works fine but m looking if there is a better way.

Comment: @JamesMills what is the advantage of storing the file as json?

Comment: single load, dict O(1) lookups. You'd still have to do your "match" though.

Comment: What is the pattern you use in `re.match`?

Comment: @JanneKarila good question. if the word in sentence matches the word in the file

Comment: Minor coding style comment - `found if re.match(sentence[0],term.lower()) else not(found)` is equivalent to just `re.match(sentence[0],term.lower())` given that the code is only executed if `found == True` holds.

Comment: Another coding style comment - you don't need to write `sentence[(len(sentence)-1)]` to get the last element of the list, you can just write `sentence[-1]`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe good point. so if re.match(sentence[0],term.lower()) is false then it will set to false correct?

Comment: @fscore Yes, clearly `re.match(..)` can be used as a boolean value since you already do so as part of an `if` - but both branches of the `if` just yield a boolean value themselves, so you may just as well drop the `if` altogether.

Comment: I want to do the'if found' block only if the word is found in file else I dont need to.

Comment: found if re.match(sentence[0],term.lower()) else not(found) gives true and false values but just re.match returns None & not false

Answer (score 3):

Here are my tips:

- Write your file out as JSON using `json.dumps()`
- Load in your file as JSON using `json.laods()`
- Separate out your data loading from your analysis into separate logical code blocks. e.g: functions

Python `dict`(s) are much faster for lookups with a complexity of O(1) than iteration which has O(n) -- So you'll get some performance benefit there as long as you load up your data file initially.

**Examples(s):**

```
from json import dumps, loads


def load_data(filename):
    return json.loads(open(filename, "r").read())

def save_data(filename, data):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(dumps(data))

data = load_data("data.json")

foo = data["word"]  # O(1) lookup of "word"
```

I would probably store your data like this:

```
data = {
    "fabulous": [7.526, 2301, 2],
    ...
}
```

You would then do:

```
stats = data.get(word, None)
if stats is not None:
    score, x, y = stats
    ...
```

**NB:** The `...` are **NOT** real code and placeholders where where you should fill in the blanks.

Comment: can you please show me a example of your tips as I never used json before.

Comment: dict better than iteration, you mean, put the file in a dictionary and do a lookup than using a for loop?

Comment: since the file had 4 columns, #fabulous   7.526   2301    2 then how can I retrieve the 1st and 2nd column?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe load the word/scores file once into memory as a dict of dicts, and then loop through each word in each sentence, checking the dict keys from your word file for each word in the sentence.

Would something like this work:

```
word_lookup = load_words(file)
for s in sentences:
    run_sentence(s)

def load_words(file):
    word_lookup = {}
    for line in file:
        (term,score,numPos,numNeg) = re.split("\t", line.strip())
        if not words.has_key(term):
            words[term] = {'score': score, 'numPos': numPos, 'numNeg': numNeg}
    return word_lookup

def run_sentence(s):
    s = standardize_sentence(s) # Assuming you want to strip punctuation, symbols, convert to lowercase, etc
    words = s.split(' ')
    first = words[0]
    last = words[-1]
    for word in words:
        word_info = check_word(word)
        if word_info:
            # Matched word, use your scores somehow (word_info['score'], etc)

def check_word(word):
    if word_lookup.has_key(word):
        return word_lookup[word]
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: what would be the output of this code? and how is it different than mine?

Comment: What is the goal output for a single sentence?  A dict summarizing scores of various words, or a dict for each word in the sentence? Main suggestion here is just to store your word file as a big dict to get the benefits of word_lookup.has_key() when checking each word in your sentence.