# loop not incrementing in list python

Tags: python, file, for-loop, file-io

I taking a file at standard input which looks like

```
12    125      "neg"       Won the match #getin . P
```

and then doing word analysis of the sentence.

I dont know why but the loop is not getting incremented in the function "unigrams_nrc". 
`i value is still 0`

Here is the code:

```
def unigrams_nrc(file):
      for line in file:
      (term,score,numPos,numNeg) = re.split("\t", line.strip())
      print sentence[i] #=> prints all 0's i does not increment
      if re.match(sentence[i],term.lower()):
         wordanalysis["unigram"] = found
      else:
         found = False
      if found:
         wordanalysis["trail_unigram"] = found if re.match(sentence[(len(sentence)-1)],term.lower()) else not(found)
         wordanalysis["lead_unigram"] = found  if re.match(sentence[0],term.lower()) else not(found)
         wordanalysis["nonzero_sscore"] = float(score) if (float(score) != 0) else 0             
         wordanalysis["sscore>0"] = (float(score) > 0)
         wordanalysis["sscore"] = (float(score) != 0)

      if re.match(tweet[len(sentence)-1],term.lower()):
         wordanalysis["sscore !=0 last token"] = (float(score) != 0)


for line in sys.stdin:
    #12    125    "neg"       Won the match #getin . P
   (tweetid,num,senti,tweets) = re.split("\t+",line.strip())
   sentence = re.split("\s+", tweets.strip())
   for i in range(0,len(sentence)):
      unigrams_nrc(file)
```

Even if I pass `i` in parameter to the function.. still no change.

Comment: unigrams_nrc is the function

Comment: It's not `i` that's 0, it's `sentence[i]`.

Comment: How can it, I mean you haven't even opened the file in your code sample.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac i havent posted that part of the code. I thought it was obvious

Comment: Are you sure of the code you have copy/paste? you have an intentation problem on the second line of unigrams_nrc...

Comment: @Loïc sorry editor problem. I have fixed that identation. The code is fine now.

Comment: Pass `i` as a parameter to the function, don't rely on it being a global.

Comment: I did but still doesnt work

Comment: Try to pass sentence to the function and do the for loops in the function maybe.

Comment: Please post the full source code without modification - there are currently some omissions which makes it impossible to answer your question without guessing. For instance, `i` is not declared in the scope of `unigrams_nrc`, so the line `print sentence[i]` should result in a `NameError`

Comment: You also currently have indentation errors. For instance, the code after `for line in file:` is not indented, so we don't know what it is in that block and what isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation is not correct, but assuming it supposed to be like [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20541659/222914), `print sentence[i]` is inside the `for line in file:` loop. Since `i` is not incremented inside the loop, you see the same thing printed many times.

When you call `unigrams_nrc` the second time, there are no more lines to read in `file`, so the loop executes zero times. To read the file again you need to close and open it, or `seek` to the beginning. Though, reading the data into eg. a dictionary, or even just a list, would speed up your program.

A quick fix would be to add `file = file.readlines()` after opening `file`; the rest of your code should work as is then.

Comment: Only prints Won 'n' number of times

Comment: yes I know i is not incremented but why is that happening. how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this

```
def foo1():
    print something[i]

def foo0():
    for i in range(0,number):
        foo1(somethingElse)
```

This is not possible!
How should `foo1` know the value of `i` and `sentence`? You have to pass the values if you want to use them.

```
def foo1(something,i):
    print something[i]

def foo0():
    for i in range(0,number):
        foo1(something,i)
```